# How do you perform an action on only NSObjects of a certain subclass in a UIView?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, subview

I have a UIView that has UILabels, UISliders, UITextboxes, etc. in it.  I want to perform an action on just the sliders.  How is this done?  Currently, I have

```
int count = 0;
for (UIView *subview in [myView subviews])
{
  if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]);
  {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"Class for object removed is %@",[subview class]);
    count ++;
  }
  //else{do nothing - subview isn't a slider, so I don't care about it}
}
NSLog(@"count = %d",count);
```

When I run this code, everything is affected (sliders, as well as the labels, textboxes, and everything else).  From what I gather from reading other posts, using isKindOfClass with arrays is kinda glitchy, but I thought that was only when trying to do `isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]`.  Or am I wrong on that?  If this nesting of `isKindOfClass` inside a `for` loop isn't allowed, how do I perform actions on just certain items on my view?

EDIT: added whole code for one implementation of this.  The count is off, and NSLog is telling me a whole bunch of UILabels are being removed.  My view is completely emptied of everything after this runs.

EDIT 2: added `;` at end of if statement like I have in my actual code. I removed it in my code and I now am getting the behavior I expected.

Comment: and I haven't created any bizarre custom subclasses of anything, I'm just using the out-of-the-box versions of the labels, sliders, views, etc.

Comment: You're missing a `[` in your `if`.

Comment: But other than that, your code looks ok. Are you sure that all the subviews are affected? Can you post your real code? What are you doing in your `if` block?

Comment: oops - I actually retyped this by hand - in my actual code I had the `[` in there, so that's not the issue.  I edited my question to add it though.

Comment: Everything here is correct; please post your actual code—the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I'm reusing the same technique to do a couple of things.  In one case, it's just a single line: `[subview removeFromSuperview];` and once it runs, my whole view is emptied out.

Comment: :facepalm: I figured it out.  I had a `;` at the end of my if line (see edit) and that was making it that the if statement wasn't actually controlling any code, so the `[subview removeFromSuperview]` was being run every time through and not just when the if statement was true.  Gah.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at warnings. Clang warnings are pretty foolproof nowadays.

Comment: It doesn't throw a warning.  I figured it would, which is why it took me so long to figure out that was the problem, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had a typo. The `;` at the end of my if statement was essentially making it like I didn't have an `if` in there at all, which is why everything was being removed from my view.  Removing the `;` made the code in my Question work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use **isMemberOfClass** instead of isKindOfClass.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the things I tried.  It ended up just being a typo, (see comments to and edit in my OP).  Fixing the typo gave me the behavior I expected.